Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^k$. Prove $\left| \min_{i=1, \ldots, k} x_i - \min_{i = 1, \ldots, k} y_i\right| \leq \lVert x-y\rVert_2$
Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^k$. We want to prove that $\left| \min_{i=1, \ldots, k} x_i - \min_{i = 1, \ldots, k} y_i\right| \leq \lVert x-y\rVert_2$, where the right hand side is the Euclidean norm.
The hint is to use the rearrangment inequality or the pigeonhole principle, but I have no idea how to proceed at all.
Thank you

Denote by $\ x_m = \min\limits_{i=1, \ldots, k} x_i \quad $ and $\quad y_n = \min\limits_{i=1, \ldots, k} y_i \ $, where $1\le m,n \le k$.
What we want to prove is then $|x_m - y_n| \le \| x-y \|_2$, or equivalently $(x_m-y_n)^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^k (x_i-y_i)^2$.
Case 1: $x_m \ge y_n$.
We have
$\begin{align}
0 \le |x_m - y_n| &= x_m - y_n \\
&\le x_n - y_n \qquad \text{by def. of } x_m
\end{align}$
which gives
$\begin{align}
(x_m - y_n)^2 &\le (x_n - y_n)^2 \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^k (x_i-y_i)^2
\end{align}$
as desired.
Case 2: $y_n \ge x_m$.
We have
$\begin{align}
0 \le |x_m - y_n| &= y_n - x_m \\
&\le y_m - x_m \qquad \text{by def. of } y_n
\end{align}$
which gives
$\begin{align}
(x_m - y_n)^2 &\le (y_m - x_m)^2 \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^k (x_i-y_i)^2
\end{align}$
as desired.
As a result, we have the desired inequality in both cases. $\blacksquare$
Alternative proof that uses rearrangement inequality:
With the same definition of $x_m$ and $y_n$, notice that it would suffice to prove that
$$(x_m-y_n)^2 \le (x_m-y_m)^2 + (x_n-y_n)^2$$
which upon expansion is equivalent to
$$2(x_m y_m + x_n y_n) \le (x_n^2 + y_m^2) + 2 x_m y_n$$
and this is true by
$\begin{align}
(x_n^2 + y_m^2) + 2 x_m y_n &\ge 2 x_n y_m + 2 x_m y_n \\
&= 2(x_n y_m + x_m y_n) \\
&\ge 2(x_m y_m + x_n y_n) \qquad \text{by reargmt. ineq. since } x_n\ge x_m, \ y_m\ge y_n
\end{align}$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Can't we only consider one of the cases WLOG?

Yes, we can. I just wanted the proof to be explicit like this.
